# How to test iPhone wake up code?

Tags: iphone, ios, wakeup

When an iOS app is woken up the applicationDidBecomeActive delegate is called.

If a device is attached to the debugger then the app will never sleep.

How do I debug problems in the wake up code?

Comment: Locking manually doesn't work? Can't you just test that without the debugger?

Comment: Nope, I don't see the bug unless it has locked up by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just delegate your applicationDidBecomeActive to other method and unittest it. You are testing your code, not Apple's wakeup callback mechanism.

Comment: Very good point but my bug is related to network stuff that I only see on wake up and I want to step through it all.